# Symfony ProgressBar: how to recreate the bar displayed at the beginning of the article

Tags: php, symfony

In the Symfony's [documentation about `ProgressBar`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html) there is a gif that shows a pretty `ProgressBar`.

In the article itself [is stated](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html#custom-formats):

> A format can span more than one line; that's very useful when you want
>   to display more contextual information alongside the progress bar (see
>   the example at the beginning of this article).

But:

1. How can I make a format span over multiple lines? Using `\n` seems not working.
2. Is there a working example of the `ProgressBar` shown in the gif?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Question 1

Using `\n` is correct as long as `\n` isn't escaped or in single quoted strings. Example:

```
/** @var ProgressBar $bar */
$bar->setFormat("Current: %current%\nMax: %max%");
```

## Question 2

The code for the referenced example is part of the unit tests. The code is available at [870cc23a/Tests/Helper/ProgressBarTest.php#L654](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/870cc23a588b67f981e8e09c94d5298c5a919346/Tests/Helper/ProgressBarTest.php#L654)

I removed the unit testing code and created a working example (tested with `symfony/console ^3.3`):

**Code**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Helper;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$bar = new ProgressBar(new ConsoleOutput(), 15);

ProgressBar::setPlaceholderFormatterDefinition('memory', function (ProgressBar $bar) {
    static $i = 0;
    $mem = 100000 * $i;
    $colors = $i++ ? '41;37' : '44;37';
    return "\033[" . $colors . 'm ' . Helper::formatMemory($mem) . " \033[0m";
});

$bar->setFormat(" \033[44;37m %title:-37s% \033[0m\n %current%/%max% %bar% %percent:3s%%\n   %remaining:-10s% %memory:37s%");
$bar->setBarCharacter($done = "\033[32m●\033[0m");
$bar->setEmptyBarCharacter($empty = "\033[31m●\033[0m");
$bar->setProgressCharacter($progress = "\033[32m➤ \033[0m");
$bar->setMessage('Starting the demo... fingers crossed', 'title');
$bar->start();

for ($i = 0; $i < 15; ++$i) {
    usleep(250000);
    $bar->advance();
}

$bar->finish();

echo "\n";
```

**Composer**

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/console": "^3.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've not tested the code, but I'll go on trust! :)